# wordpress adding javascript functions on specific pages getting uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, wordpress, menu

I have searched the net, maybe not the right place,s but have been trying to simply insert a dropdown list with a "go" button that when selected will take me to a page for that state. Here is the code I have added to my theme's function page:

```
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
  if (is_page ('covid-19-resources-for-artists')) { 
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // your javscript code goes here
          function gotosite() {
  window.location = document.getElementById("menu").value; // JQuery:  $("#menu").val();
}// your javscript code goes here
        </script>
    <?php
  }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
```

and here is the html on the page

```
<select id="menu">
<option value="">Please Choose...</option>
<option value="http://www.google.com/">Google</option>
<option value="http://www.youtube.com/">Youtube</option>
<option value="http://www.pinterest.com/">Pinterest</option>
</select>
<button id="go" onclick="gotosite()">Go</button>
```

the console error is: 
?preview=true:324 Uncaught ReferenceError: gotosite is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (?preview=true:324)

Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong? Supposedly wordpress loads everything automatically? Thanks!

Comment: Did you check if the function is returned in that page?

Comment: you can also `onclick='window.location = document.getElementById("menu").value'`

Comment: @kaize not sure how to do that?

Comment: @ariel would the whole thing look like this - <button id="go" onclick='window.location = document.getElementById("menu").value'">Go</button>